# Colocar vídeo do Youtube como background de site

Tags: jquery, youtube

Quero colocar um vídeo de background em uma tela de espera. Tem como fazer isso puxando um vídeo do youtube sem mostrar os botões padrões e que ele inicie automaticamente?
O Jquery que tenho para colocar o vídeo que está no meu host.

```
$('body').bg({
position:"fixed",
zIndex:-1,
mp4:'meuvideo.mp4',
ogv:'meuvideo.ogv',
webm:'meuvideo.webm',
poster:'meuvideo.jpg',
opacity:0.5
});
```

Aqui eu puxo o vídeo direto do meu servidor, e do youtube?

Comment: Mesmo com background não sei se dá, mas se não fizer diferença pode tentar assim: https://jsfiddle.net/ks8hu650/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, boa tarde.

É possível colocar um vídeo do youtube como background usando um link modificado do próprio youtube. Este link contém informações adicionais tanto em `pathInfo` quanto em `parameters`

Utilizando um iFrame, como o usuário @Miguel comentou, é possível deixar o vídeo como um background mesmo:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
</iframe>
```

Note que é preciso alterar o `ID`do link postado acima com o ID correspondente do vídeo.
Sendo que:

- o parametro `autoplay=1` significa que o vídeo iniciará automaticamente.
- o parametro `controls=0` significa que não haverá opções de controle, tais como play, volume, config, tela cheia, legendas etc.
- o parametro `showinfo=0` significa que o player não mostrará o nome do vídeo
- o parametro `autohide=1` significa que a barra de progresso do vídeo ficará invisível.

Você pode ler informações [aqui](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)